# Is it possible to insert Antlers tag in the middle of Class names?

Tags: tailwind-css, statamic

I have the following HTML with **Tailwind** classes to display a full screen header image in **Statamic** CMS:

```
<header class="w-full h-full bg-[url('/img/headers/robert-patient-blue-overlay.png')] bg-cover bg-center flex justify-center items-center">...</header>
```

and have been trying to replace `/img/headers/robert-patient-blue-overlay.png` with `{{ header_image }}` so that is can be edited in the CMS, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

using `[url('"{{ header_image }}"')]` doesn't work, nor does `[url("{{ header_image }}")]` or `[url({{ header_image }})]`... is it just not doable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not doable. This is because Tailwind scans your source code as plain text, so it sees `bg-[url({{ header_image }})]` **literally**. Thus, it sees the strings `bg-[url({{`, `header_image` and `}})]` which are all invalid Tailwind classes.

As a work-around, you could consider using the `style` attribute instead like:

```html
<header class="…" style="background-image: url({{ header_image }})">
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, makes sense. It didn't like the above, unfortunately. I tried `style="background-image: url('{{ header_image }}')"` and VS Code didn't complain about that, but it still doesn't display. I guess it's not possible...

Comment: sorry, don't mean console, I meant the source code in the inspector in the browser

Comment: Your latest comment should work. That's how I do it in Antlers too. Maybe you didn't set your field markup properly. You may have to set max_files = 1 in your field's blueprint to be able to call out the image in a single tag like you have done above. Another way to debug is to see what URL is being rendered on the browser's console/inspect element. You'd see what's missing precisely there. Last resort, write {{ header_image | dump }} in your antlers file to see if there's any value there.